# How can I call the function in fragment tab from fragment tabhost in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

So , in my project there is 6 tab. In main activity , it create the tab host with tab like this

```
tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator(""),Home.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("assistant").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_assistant)), Shop.class,null); //not clickable right now
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("coupon").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_coupon)), Coupon.class,null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("shop").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_shop)), Shop.class,null);
```

Then , at some point , I would like to achieve:

1) change the tab to the tab 2

2) call the function in tab 2

so , I tried using boardcast receiver, but it seems it run but the onReceive is not trigger on the tab 2

in the main class

```
        setTab(0);
        msg.putExtra("isEnter", 0);
    sendBroadcast(msg);
    Log.d("test1","boardcast");
```

in the tab2 class

```
private class DataUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("test1","test");
            if (intent.getAction().equals("shopStatus")) {
                Log.d("test1","test2");
                int type = intent.getIntExtra("isEnter",-1);
                Log.d("test1",""+type);
                if (type == 0) {
                    helper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    helper_txt.setText(R.string.enter_mall);
                    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("isShowHelper", true).commit();
                            ctxActivity.setTab(4);
                        }
                    });
                    no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            helper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for helping, any way can achieve it will accept.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted my code below. I don't know wether it will siuts you or not. But, this code will give you some idea.

public class CollisionTabView extends FragmentActivity implements
OnClickListener, OnTabChangeListener, CallAPIFinishedListener,OtherDriverInfoData,AccidentInfoData,AdditionalDataInfo,PoliceInfoData{

```
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
Button collisionhome, collision_center;
TextView title;
int previousId = 0, previous = 0;
String tTitle = null;

boolean back = false;

private enum Tabs {
    accident_info, other_driver, police_info, additional_nfo;
}

SQLiteDatabase database;
DatabaseHelper dataHelper;
DealershipApplication application;
CallAPIFinishedListener callAPIFinishedListener;
CollisionTabView mContext;
static Bundle data;
private ExceptionHandler miCrashHandler;


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.collision_tabview);
    callAPIFinishedListener = this;
    mContext = this;
    miCrashHandler=new ExceptionHandler(mContext);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(miCrashHandler);
    new Accident_info(this,this);
    new Other_Driver_Info(this,this);
    new AdditionalInfo(this,this);
    new PoliceInfo(this,this);
    application = (DealershipApplication) getApplicationContext();
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collisiontitle);
    title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.collisiontab_collisioninfo));
    title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    collisionhome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.collisionhome);
    collisionhome.setText("Back");
    collisionhome.setOnClickListener(this);
    application.changeTypeface(title, collisionhome);
    collisionhome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    collision_center = (Button) findViewById(R.id.collision_centerbutton);
    collision_center.setOnClickListener(this);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("accident_info").setIndicator(
                    "Accident Info"), Accident_info.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("other_driver").setIndicator(
                    "Other Driver's Info"), Other_Driver_Info.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("police_info").setIndicator("Police Info"),
            PoliceInfo.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("additional_nfo").setIndicator(
                    "Additional Info"), AdditionalInfo.class, null);
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    setTabsStyle();
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    setActive(0, R.drawable.tab_active, R.drawable.tab_inactive,
            R.drawable.tab_inactive, R.drawable.tab_inactive);
    back = false;
    database = DealershipApplication.openDb(mContext);
    dataHelper = DealershipApplication.getDatabaseHelper(mContext);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    try{
        /*if(tabreceiver!=null) CollisionTabView.this.unregisterReceiver(tabreceiver);*/

        Accident_info.updated = false;
        Other_Driver_Info.updated = false;
        PoliceInfo.updated = false;
        AdditionalInfo.updated = false;

    }catch(Exception e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

private void setTabsStyle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

        final View view = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);

        if (view != null) {

            final View textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            if (textView instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                ((TextView) textView).setSingleLine(false);

                textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                if (i == 0) {
                    ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_active);

                    ((TextView) textView).setTextAppearance(this,
                            R.style.collisiontext);
                    ((TextView) textView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


                    ((TextView) textView).setTextAppearance(this,
                            R.style.collisiontext);
                    ((TextView) textView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    // title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.collisiontab_policeinfo));

                    ((TextView) textView).setTextAppearance(this,
                            R.style.collisiontext);
                    ((TextView) textView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    // title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.collisiontab_additionalinfo));

                    ((TextView) textView).setTextAppearance(this,
                            R.style.collisiontext);
                    ((TextView) textView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.collision_centerbutton:
        collision_centerbutton();
        break;
    case R.id.collisionhome:

        back = true;
        collisionhome();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

private void collisionhome() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean check1 = Accident_info.updated;
    boolean check2 = Other_Driver_Info.updated;
    boolean check3 = PoliceInfo.updated;
    boolean check4 = AdditionalInfo.updated;

    if (check1 == false && check2 == false && check3 == false
            && check4 == false) {
        finish();
    } else {

        switch (mTabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
        case 0:
            tTitle = "Accident Info";
            break;
        case 1:
            tTitle = "Other Driver's Info";
            break;
        case 2:
            tTitle = "Police Info";
            break;
        case 3:
            tTitle = "Additional Info";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        setDialog(mTabHost.getCurrentTab(), tTitle, true);
    }
}

private void collision_centerbutton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent
        .setData(Uri.parse("tel:"
                + getResources().getString(
                        R.string.collision_center_phno)));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed"+ activityException);
    }
}

private void setTab(int pre, boolean clear) {
    callFunction(pre, clear);

}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean tab3 = PoliceInfo.updated;
    boolean tab2 = Other_Driver_Info.updated;
    boolean tab4 = AdditionalInfo.updated;
    boolean tab1 = Accident_info.updated;

    boolean vehicle = Accident_info.vehicleSelected;
    if (!vehicle) {
        new DoToast(getBaseContext(), getResources().getString(
                R.string.select_vehicle_toast), 200);

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    } else {        
        Log.d("Collistion Tab View:::::::::", "Inside Else::::of Tab Changed::::");
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)            
                CollisionTabView.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(CollisionTabView.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),      
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

        // previous = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        Tabs tabs = Tabs.valueOf(tabId);
        Log.i("previous", previous + " previous");
        previousId = previous;
        switch (tabs) {
        case accident_info:
            previous = 0;
            setActive(0, R.drawable.tab_active, R.drawable.tab_inactive,
                    R.drawable.tab_inactive, R.drawable.tab_inactive);
            tTitle = "Accident Info";
            break;
        case other_driver:
            Log.d("Collistion Tab View:::::::::", "Inside Other Driver infor::::");
            previous = 1;
            tTitle = "Other Driver's Info";
            setActive(1, R.drawable.tab_inactive, R.drawable.tab_active,
                    R.drawable.tab_inactive, R.drawable.tab_inactive);
            break;
        case police_info:
            previous = 2;
            tTitle = "Police Info";
            setActive(2, R.drawable.tab_inactive, R.drawable.tab_inactive,
                    R.drawable.tab_active, R.drawable.tab_inactive);
            break;
        case additional_nfo:
            previous = 3;
            tTitle = "Additional Info";
            setActive(3, R.drawable.tab_inactive, R.drawable.tab_inactive,
                    R.drawable.tab_inactive, R.drawable.tab_active);
            break;
        default:
            break;


        }
        if (tab1)
            setDialog(0, "Accident Info", false);

        if (tab2){
            Log.d("Collistion Tab View:::::::::", "Inside Tab2 View is not Saved:::::");
            setDialog(1, "Other Driver's Info", false);
        }
        if (tab3)
            setDialog(2, "Police Info", false);

        if (tab4)
            setDialog(3, "Additional Info", false);
    }
}

public void callFunction(int pre, boolean clear) {

    switch (pre) {
    case 0:

        try {
            Accident_info acciinfo = new Accident_info();
            if (clear){
                acciinfo.setClear();
            }
            else
                acciinfo.Insert(callAPIFinishedListener);
            Accident_info.updated = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        try {
            Other_Driver_Info otherinfo = new Other_Driver_Info();
            if (clear)
                otherinfo.setClear();
            else
                otherinfo.Insert(callAPIFinishedListener);
            Other_Driver_Info.updated = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        try {
            PoliceInfo policeinfo = new PoliceInfo();
            if (clear)
                PoliceInfo.setClear();
            else
                policeinfo.Insert(callAPIFinishedListener);
            PoliceInfo.updated = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        try {
            AdditionalInfo additionalinfo = new AdditionalInfo();
            if (clear)
                AdditionalInfo.setClear();
            else
                additionalinfo.Insert(callAPIFinishedListener);
            AdditionalInfo.updated = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

private void setActive(int tabInactive, int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(tabInactive);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(t1);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(t2);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(t3);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(t4);
}

public void setDialog(final int pre, final String title, final boolean backpage) {

    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            CollisionTabView.this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle(title);
    helpBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    helpBuilder.setMessage("Do you want to save data?");
    helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            boolean vehicle = Accident_info.vehicleSelected;
            if (!vehicle) {
                new DoToast(getBaseContext(), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.select_vehicle_toast),
                        200);
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            } else {
                setTab(pre, false);
            }
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    helpBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing but close the dialog
            // mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            Accident_info.updated = false;
            Other_Driver_Info.updated = false;
            PoliceInfo.updated = false;
            AdditionalInfo.updated = false;
            dialog.cancel();
            setTab(pre, true);          
            DealershipApplication.setSaveStatus(title,true);
            Log.d("Collision Tab View:::::::::::::","Tab Name::::::::::::::"+pre);
            if (backpage){
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)            
                        CollisionTabView.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(CollisionTabView.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),      
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                finish();
            }



        }
    });
    AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    helpDialog.show();
}

public void onTaskFinished(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("result", result + " resultresult");
    // processResult(result);
    try {
        JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(result);
        int responseCode = Integer.parseInt(jb.getString("resultCode"));
        int collisionId = Integer.parseInt(jb.getString("CollisionID"));
        Log.i("collisionId", collisionId + " collisionIdcollisionId");
        SharedPreferences myPrefs;
        Editor prefsEditor;
        data = new Bundle();
        switch (responseCode) {
        case 0:
            myPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(DealershipApplication.PREFERENCE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putInt("collision_id", collisionId);
            prefsEditor.commit();

            collisionId = myPrefs.getInt("collision_id", 0);
            Log.i("collisionId", collisionId + " collisionId");

            data.putInt("Id", collisionId);

            int value = dataHelper.UpdateCollisionId(database, -1, data);

            if (value == 1) {

                prefsEditor.putString("userid", jb.getString("userId"));
                prefsEditor.commit();

                new DoToast(mContext, getResources().getString(
                        R.string.saved_success), 200);

            } else {
                prefsEditor.putString("user_id", null);
                prefsEditor.commit();
            }
            if (back) {
                finish();
            }

            break;

        default:
            dataHelper.deleteCollisionIdById(database, -1);
            break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void getOtherInfoResultData() {
    if(mTabHost!=null){
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_active);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3)
        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
    }
}


@Override
public void getAccidentInfoResultData() {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_active);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);

}

@Override
public void getAdditionalInfoResultData() {
    finish();
}

@Override
public void getPoliceInfoResultData() {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_inactive);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3)
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_active);
}
```

}